# GAMLSS model can't compute vcov using family BEINF0

Tags: covariance-matrix, gamlss

I am using gamlss to analyze inherently proportional data for % mildew on leaf area. This is an average value of 10 leaves per replicate. I only have 3 replicates. I used BEINF0 for some datasets that were zero inflated  when it was the best fit, and distribution BE when it was not (BE fit was better than BEZI). For one data base, the model output warns that "vcov has failed, option qr is used instead".

My model is very simple:
`leafinfA2<-gamlss(AveProp~Treatment,family=BEINF0,data=LeafAmadoAug27)`

The model fit still looks good (graphically) and the Treatment is a significant factor based on AIC and comparing with the null model using LR.test(). I have 2 issues. First, I am not sure how this affects the interpretation of the AIC and p value by itself and when discussing these results in comparison to the other models were type="vcov" was used. My second issue is that when I try to run a multiple comparison for the Treatment levels using emmeans(), I get "Warning: Negative variance estimate obtained!" and this output:

```
contrast odds.ratio     SE  df null z.ratio p.value
 CT / L       0.0689    NaN Inf    1     NaN     NaN
 CT / Un      1.2932    NaN Inf    1     NaN     NaN
 CT / VC      0.1381    NaN Inf    1     NaN     NaN
 CT / W       0.2598    NaN Inf    1     NaN     NaN
 L / Un      18.7698 7.3684 Inf    1   7.469  <.0001
 L / VC       2.0043 0.3174 Inf    1   4.390  0.0001
 L / W        3.7706 0.5834 Inf    1   8.579  <.0001
 Un / VC      0.1068 0.0430 Inf    1  -5.556  <.0001
 Un / W       0.2009 0.0805 Inf    1  -4.006  0.0004
 VC / W       1.8813 0.3371 Inf    1   3.527  0.0024

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

As you can see, there seems to be an issue with the Treatment level CT, in which all the values are zero. I am guessing this is why it can't get the variance covariance matrix and standard errors. If I use the family BEZI, I don't get the the warning, and it gives me the following values:

```
 CT / L       0.0689 1.16e+03 Inf    1   0.000  1.0000
 CT / Un      1.2931 2.17e+04 Inf    1   0.000  1.0000
 CT / VC      0.1381 2.32e+03 Inf    1   0.000  1.0000
 CT / W       0.2598 4.36e+03 Inf    1   0.000  1.0000
 L / Un      18.7682 7.37e+00 Inf    1   7.470  <.0001
 L / VC       2.0043 3.17e-01 Inf    1   4.390  0.0001
 L / W        3.7706 5.83e-01 Inf    1   8.579  <.0001
 Un / VC      0.1068 4.30e-02 Inf    1  -5.557  <.0001
 Un / W       0.2009 8.00e-02 Inf    1  -4.006  0.0006
 VC / W       1.8813 3.37e-01 Inf    1   3.527  0.0038

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

Is there an issue with these results with p-values of 1.000 for CT? I read the warning for the vcov matrix can happen as a result of overfitting, does it look like this is still an issue using family BEZI?

Also, the fit of the model, assessed graphically using plot(), doesn't look as good as with BEINF0. Is there a way to eliminate this issue with family BEINF0? or otherwise, how can I improve the fit for the model with the family BEZI?

Thanks for your help!